# want to check my grammar before i send this to my recruiter

Tags: meaning-in-context, grammar

Hope my training is confirmed, so I would like to know about my appoinment details , could you please let me know about it. (Is this polite or not please help me )

Comment: Hi Nishen, we don't normally do proofreading, and that's what this is. If you have specific concerns about any part of this sentence, please do a bit of research about it and then explain what specifically you are confused about.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A more formal way to write this would be:

I hope my training has been confirmed. If so, I would like to know the particulars regarding my appointment. I kindly request that you let me know as soon as possible.